# Disable back-page button in browser

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I create auth app with routing in angular 2 with typescript. And now my task is disabled back button in browser from form `localhost/form1` to `localhost/login`; how implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really block the back button since it's a browser behavior. What you can do instead is to create a guard to handle every request, and if the request is done to load /login and the user is already loggued, simply redirect to the previous page.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, i add something that you tell, i mean AuthGuard. But not for back page. Thanks for response.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this in my angular cordova app to prevent app from exiting as following. Contrary to most comments I've found I had to use the "document" object instead of the "window" object to capture the backbutton event

```
// Prevent from exiting app by hook into document backbutton
@HostListener('document:backbutton', ['$event'])
    onPopState(event) {
    alert('Start page');
}
```

Usage in a component

```
import { Component, HostListener  } from '@angular/core';

export class myComponent {
    constructor() {}

    // Prevent from exiting app by hook into document backbutton
    @HostListener('document:backbutton', ['$event'])
       onPopState(event) {
       alert('Start page');
    }
}
```

Comment: This 'document:backbutton' doesn't seems to exist for web browser.

Answer (score -1):

**step 1:** Import Locatoion from angular commmon

```
import {Location} from "@angular/common";
```

**step 2:** Initialise in constructor

```
private commonService: CommonService
```

step 3: Add function in ngOnInit of the respective coponent,

```
this.location.subscribe(currentLocation => {
if (currentLocation.url === '*/basic-info*') {
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        history.go(1);
    }
}
```

});

**Note:** Here **/basic-info** will be replaced by your path.

If first time it is not working, try adding outside subscribe,

```
let currentUrl = window.location.href;
let tmpVar = currentUrl.includes('/basic-info');
if (currentUrl.includes('/basic-info')) {
  window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    history.go(1);
  }
}
```